Can't Find My Entire Project
I spent a lot of time making a project & can't find it today. I've tried searching for it in the finder with .blend
I remember saving it & see something like looks like the project but it's a document file and I get the warning when I try to open it: There is no application set to open the document “title.blend1”.
My other question is - there was a point when my MacBook shutdown unexpectedly - if so does it recover blender files. Trying to connect the dots and hopefully find my beloved project. Thanks in advance!

.Blend1 files are backup Blender files. If you go to File > Open... in Blender the File View dialog has a filter icon top-right. Click the down arrow beside it and and you can check the Backup .blend Files option on the list of file types. You should then see the .blend1 file that you found and it should open in Blender just like a normal Blend file. However, it will only have the contents from the last time you successfully saved your file.

You could also try File > Recover > Auto Save.. but that will depend on your settings under Preferences.
